# Flink localhost dashboard not working despite cluster starting

Tags: windows, localhost, apache-flink

I have downloaded `Flink 1.5.0` and ran the start-cluster script and the cluster seems to have started successfully:

```
$ ./bin/start-cluster.sh
Starting cluster.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host LAPTOP-HRAHBL24.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host LAPTOP-HRAHBL24.
```

However, I am when I access http://localhost:8081/ the connection is being refused. I followed the question to un-comment the localhost lines in my hosts file:
https://superuser.com/questions/1008349/unable-to-connect-to-localhost-after-windows-10-upgrade

I checked the logs and I have this error in it:"/d/Programs/flink-1.5.0/bin/flink-daemon.sh: line 131: C:\Program: No such file or directory" I had this error with `Flink 1.10.1`, I tried searching it but couldn't find anything

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I would start by looking in the Flink logs for clues.

Comment: Thanks. I did. I have this error: "/d/Programs/flink-1.5.0/bin/flink-daemon.sh: line 131: C:\Program: No such file or directory"
I had this error with Flink 1.10.1, I tried searching it but couldn't find anything...

Comment: Can you upgrade to a more modern version of Flink? Version 1.5 is ancient at this point.

Comment: I had the same error with Flink 1.0.1

Comment: This is the output of the start-cluster script with Flink 10.1:
[ERROR] Unexpected result: /d/Programs/flink-1.10.1/bin/config.sh: line 633: C:\Program: No such file or directory
[ERROR] The last line of the BashJavaUtils outputs is expected to be the execution result, following the prefix 'BASH_JAVA_UTILS_EXEC_RESULT:'
/d/Programs/flink-1.10.1/bin/config.sh: line 633: C:\Program: No such file or directory
[ERROR] Could not get JVM parameters properly.
Isn't it the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the space in "Program Files", so I set the java home in conf/flink-conf.xml instead and this error was gone.

Comment: having the same issue with flink 1.16, setting `env.java.home` doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

In conf/flink-conf.yaml, set java home with this variable env.java.home

Comment: having the same issue with flink 1.16, setting `env.java.home` doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

For Mac in my case, I had to bring the flink cluster using sudo permissions after which the cluster came up successfully

```
sudo ./bin/start-cluster.sh
```