# Cannot access Flink dashboard localhost:8081 on windows

Tags: windows, localhost, apache-flink

I follow the [first steps](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/local_installation/) to install Flink.
I can start the cluster without any problem

```
$ start-cluster.sh
Starting cluster.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host DESKTOP-....
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host DESKTOP-....
```

But I don't get any status from

```
$ ps aux | grep flink
```

I can also not access the dashboard via localhost:8081.

There is an older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229011/flink-localhost-dashboard-not-working-despite-cluster-starting) having these issues, but the solution didn't work for me, since the described conf files do no longer exist, apparently.

My JAVA_HOME is set as C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_311 to avoid issues with the space in Program Files.

Answer (score 5):

This still seems to be problematic. I tried to run from Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

I have the following versions: java 11.0.16 and flink 1.15.2.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
export FLINK_HOME=/mnt/c/Projects/Apache/flink-1.15.2
```

I set the following in flink-conf.yaml

```
rest.port: 8081
rest.address: localhost
rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0
```

Whereby I changed the bind address for localhost to 0.0.0.0 this seems to have fixed the problem.

```
$FLINK_HOME/bin/start-cluster.sh
```

Now I can access the Flink Web Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Merjin!   rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0 fixed the issue.  Please correct the spelling from "rest.bind-adress: 0.0.0.0" to "rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0" and your answer will be perfect!

Comment: Thanks @Merjin. rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0 in conf/flink-conf.yaml fixed the issue. The default value of rest.bind-address: localhost seems preventing it.
It works even after keeping res.port: 8081 commented.

Comment: wasted my half day for this issue... Thanks..! it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the logs in the `/logs` folder? I'm suspecting that `C:\Program Files\` could still cause issues because of the space there.

Comment: It says that these couldn't be found:

Fehler: Hauptklasse org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden

Fehler: Hauptklasse org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden

Comment: This implies that the Flink cluster wasn't able to start. In most cases this is because the Java installation couldn't be found. Have you seen/tried https://gist.github.com/codspire/0020b60d5e1cc1f40d312be11829687d ?

Answer (score 0):

go to download Flink folder and try bash command

```
$./bin/start-cluster.sh --daemon bootstrap-server localhost:8081
```

and run code one more

```
$ ./bin/flink run examples/streaming/WordCount.jar
```

if you finished run above code which not issue, go to localhost:8081