# Flink installation Maven build failure flink-runtime-web

Tags: windows, maven, github, apache-flink

I follow the installation instructions for Apache Flink on github:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/flink.git
cd flink
mvn clean package -DskipTests # this will take up to 10 minutes
```

Tough the maven build takes much longer than "up to 10 minutes" and fails with

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.0:npm (npm run
> ci-check) on project flink-runtime-web: Failed to run task: 'npm run
> ci-check' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process
> exited with an error

Log:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node\node_modules  \npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ci-check'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'preci-check', 'ci-check', 'postci-check' ]
5 info lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~preci-check: flink-dashboard@2.0.0
6 info lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~ci-check: flink-dashboard@2.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~ci-check: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~ci-check: PATH: C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node_modules.bin;C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node;C:\Users\julia\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\julia\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\protoc\bin;C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\julia\anaconda3;C:\Users\julia\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\hdp\hadoop-3.3.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1;C:\hdp\hadoop-3.3.0\sbin;C:\hdp\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop3.2\bin;C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Coursier\data\bin;C:\hdp\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop3.2\python;C:\hdp\flink-1.14.2\bin;C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl;
9 verbose lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~ci-check: CWD: C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard
10 silly lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~ci-check: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run lint && npm run build' ]
11 silly lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~ci-check: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle flink-dashboard@2.0.0~ci-check: Failed to exec ci-check script
13 verbose stack Error: flink-dashboard@2.0.0 ci-check: `npm run lint && npm run build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit   (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid flink-dashboard@2.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node\node.exe" "C:\hdp\flink\flink-runtime-web\web-dashboard\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "ci-check"
18 verbose node v12.14.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error flink-dashboard@2.0.0 ci-check: `npm run lint && npm run build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the flink-dashboard@2.0.0 ci-check script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NPM installed already on your machine? This errors usually is encountered when there's a problem with a local NPM installation that prevents the Flink web interface from building. If you don't need this, you could consider skipping it by running `mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pskip-webui-build`

Comment: I just recently installed node.js :/   
Thanks! What does "-Pskip-webui-build" do? Why does this skip the install for flink-runtime-web?

Comment: It's an additional Maven profile to skip building the web interface. It's an option to decrease build time since not a lot of engineers want to build the web interface.

Comment: Thanks, it build it successful. Sadly building it this way didn't solve my main [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736171/cannot-access-flink-dashboard-localhost8081-on-windows).Still cannot run flink web cluster.

Comment: As in you can't start a Flink cluster at all? If so, did you modify anything in the source code? Do you also have that problem with the downloaded version?